# Can I display 1 widget in 2 widget areas?

Tags: wordpress

I have 1 widget. I want to display it in 2 widget areas with 2 different front-end styles. So how can I do it? In Wordpress, can I check what widget area that the widget is currently in? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're trying to do or what you've tried, but the short answer is yes, you can re-use widgets in more than one area and style them independently with css.

If it's a widgetized area accessible through the widget menu, it would then be considered 2 different widgets, so changing one in the widgets menu would not change the other. For example, that's fine if it's something like an article feed, but if it's a menu and you want to use it twice without modifying 2 menus then you would have to add it with php and not through the widget menu.

If you're using Gutenberg and the widget is a widget block, then you can add it as a reusable block and modify every instance at once.

Comment: Your first words are reason enough to vote to close the question, not answer it. Not all questions can or should be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer